# Need help porting a wait free trie from C to Rust

Tags: rust, concurrency, parallel-processing, atomic, wait-free

For some HPC computing I need to port a wait free trie (but you can think of it as a tree) from C to Rust. The trie is 99% read 1% write, and is used both in parallel-concurrent scenarios , and concurrent only scenarios (single thread with multiple coroutines). The size of the tree is usually between 100kb and 8 mb.

Basically the tree is like:

```rust
pub struct WFTrie {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    leaves: Vec<Leaf>,
    updates: Vec<Update>,
    update_pos: AtomicUsize,
    update_cap: usize,
}

//.... 
let mut wftrie = WFTrie::new(); 
let wftrie_ptr = AtomicPtr::new(&mut wftrie);

//....
```

As you can see the trie already uses something very similar to the arena approach that many suggests, by using a vec and storing

- When I want to update, I do a `fetch_and_add` on `update_pos`. If it's greater than `update_cap` I return an error (size exhausted), otherwise I'm sure sure my coroutine/thread has exclusive access to `updates[update_pos % update_cap]`, where I can put my update
- Every X updates (`if update_pos % 8 == 0 { //update tree}` ) a coroutine will clone the tree, apply all pending updates, and then `compare_and_swap` the `wftrie_ptr`
- When I want to read I do an atomic load on `wtftrie_ptr` and I can access the tree, taking care of considering also the pending updates.

My questions are:

- If I have multiple coroutines having an immutable reference, how can I have one coroutine doing updates? What's the most idiomatic way to translate this to rust?
- If a coroutine is still holding a ref to the old tree during an update what happens? Should I replace the AtomicPtr with Arc?
- Does this design fit well with the rust borrow checker or am I going to have to use unsafe?
- In the case of concurrent only scenario, can I drop atomics without using unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly informed about HPC, but I hope I can give you some useful pointers about programming with concurrency in Rust.

> … I'm sure sure my coroutine/thread has exclusive access to updates[update_pos], where I can put my update

This is necessary, but not sufficient: if you are going to write to data behind an `&` reference (whether from multiple threads or not), then you are implementing *interior mutability*, and you *must* always signal that to the compiler by using some cell type. The minimal at-your-own-risk way to do that is with an [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html), which provides no synchronization and is `unsafe` to operate on:

```rust
    updates: Vec<UnsafeCell<Update>>,
```

but you can also use a safer type such as a lock (that you know will never experience any contention since you arranged that no other thread is using it). In Rust, all locks and other interior mutability primitives — including atomics — are built on top of `UnsafeCell`; it is how you tell the compiler “this memory is exempt from the usual rule of N readers xor 1 writer”.

> Every X updates … a coroutine will clone the tree …

You will have to arrange so that the clone isn't trying to read the data that is being modified. That is, don't clone the `WFTrie`, but only the `nodes` and `leaves` vectors since that's the data you actually need.

If you were to use `UnsafeCell` or a lock as I mentioned above, then you'll find that you *can't* just clone the `updates` vector, precisely because it wouldn't be sound to do so without explicit locking. If necessary, you can read it step-by-step in some way that agrees with your concurrency requirements.

> If I have multiple coroutines having an immutable reference, how can I have one coroutine doing updates? What's the most idiomatic way to translate this to rust?

I'm not aware of a specifically Rust-y way to do this. It sounds like you could manage it with just an `AtomicBool`, but you probably know more than I do here.

> If a coroutine is still holding a ref to the old tree during an update what happens? Should I replace the AtomicPtr with Arc?

Yes, this is a problem. Note that `AtomicPtr` is `unsafe` to read, because it does not guarantee the pointed-to thing is alive. You need a way to use something like `Arc` *and* atomically swap which specific `Arc` is in the `wftrie_ptr` location; the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/latest/arc_swap/) library provides that.

> Does this design fit well with the rust borrow checker or am I going to have to use unsafe?

From a perspective of *using* the data structure, it seems fine — it will not be any more inconvenient to read or write than any other data structure held behind `Arc`.

For implementation, you will not be having very much “fight with the borrow checker” because you are not going to be writing functions with very many borrows — since your data structure *owns its contents*. But, insofar as you are writing your own concurrency primitives with `unsafe`, you will need to be careful to *obey all the memory rules anyway*. Remember that `unsafe` is not a license to disregard the rules; it's telling the compiler “I'm going to obey the rules but in a way you can't check”.

> In the case of concurrent only scenario, can I drop atomics without using unsafe?

Yes; in a no-threads scenario, you can use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) for all purposes that atomics would serve.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer, very informative. You are right about the update vec, my question was worded poorly in the sense that the update vec is treated as a ring buffer, it's never cloned and updates are appended at `position % len(updates)`